# How to compare otp number without reload page which send in sms?

Tags: laravel

I want to compare otp numbers, which i type in textbox and sms otp sent to the number through api calling controller in laravel.

i use laravel5.6 and php 7.2.3

```
 public function otpverify(Request $req)
    {
        $otpenter=$req->txtotp;
        if ($otpenter==$otp) 
        {
            return redirect()->action('JaincountController@create')
        }
        else
        {
            return view('jaincount_user/verification');
        }
    }
    public function makeRequest(Request $req)
    {
            $client = new Client();
            $otp=rand(10000,4);
            // $data=
            $data = array('adhar'=>$req->txtadharnumber,'drp'=>$req->drpcode,'mobilenumber'=>$req->txtnumber);


            $response = $client->request('POST','http://192.168.1.9/jaincountapi/public/api/otpsms',[
            'form_params'=>[
                'adharcardnumber'=>$req->txtadharnumber,
                'mobilecode'=>$req->drpcode,
                'mobilenumber'=>$req->txtnumber,
                'otp'=>$otp
            ]
            ]);
            $response = $response->getBody();
            return json_decode($response,true);
    }
```

i want to compare textbox otp number and sms otp number sent through api calling and redirect with another controller in laravel5.6

Comment: Which part is not working here? What is the exact issue?

Comment: otp get through sms but otp not compare and how to compare that send otp with textbox otp number

Comment: Are you able to read the opt from message?

Comment: means otp not get in resopnse but it's readable in mobile sms

Comment: You are capturing opt value on server inside any db?

Comment: no otp not store in any inside db it's generate through rand() and in api calling store one variable only

Comment: I'm just wondering how you are going to compare the values then does these both variables having values? `$otpenter`==`$otp`

Comment: in $otpenter value come from textbox and $otp in that variable which is send in api so i am confuse how i compare and redirect another controller.

Comment: You must hold / save the value somewhere else when you are generating with `rand()` before sending to API, so with user will input opt in textbox  you can just retrieve value from there and compare with that.

Comment: If I store that value in one variable and that I pass in SMS and all then what do

Comment: If you store value in $variable.... it would not be available in next request. It only available for that session... when the next time you'll get request to validate the value... it would be empty.

Comment: For that I store that variable in other session variable and then that variable pass in other controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is you must store your otp in database or in session variable.

(Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)
You can store otp in database like

```
public function makeRequest(Request $req)
{
        $client = new Client();
        $otp=rand(10000,4);
        // $data=
        $data = array('adhar'=>$req->txtadharnumber,'drp'=>$req->drpcode,'mobilenumber'=>$req->txtnumber);

        //CHANGES
        User::where('phone_number',$req->txtnumber)->update(['otp'=>$otp]);


        $response = $client->request('POST','http://192.168.1.9/jaincountapi/public/api/otpsms',[
        'form_params'=>[
            'adharcardnumber'=>$req->txtadharnumber,
            'mobilecode'=>$req->drpcode,
            'mobilenumber'=>$req->txtnumber,
            'otp'=>$otp
        ]
        ]);
        $response = $response->getBody();
        return json_decode($response,true);
}
```

you can retrieve it using eloquent in Laravel using

```
public function otpverify(Request $req)
 {
    $otpenter=$req->txtotp;
    //CHANGES
    $otp = User::where('phone_number', $phone_number)->first()->otp;

    if ($otpenter==$otp) 
    {
        return redirect()->action('JaincountController@create')
    }
    else
    {
        return view('jaincount_user/verification');
    }
}
```

after entering the correct otp clear that in database.

Or you can use session.you can use session in two ways

1.php default session
2.Laravel Session

let us see php default session
(documentation:https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

```
public function makeRequest(Request $req)
   {
        $client = new Client();
        $otp=rand(10000,4);
        // $data=
        $data = array('adhar'=>$req->txtadharnumber,'drp'=>$req->drpcode,'mobilenumber'=>$req->txtnumber);

        //CHANGES
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['otp'] = $otp


        $response = $client->request('POST','http://192.168.1.9/jaincountapi/public/api/otpsms',[
        'form_params'=>[
            'adharcardnumber'=>$req->txtadharnumber,
            'mobilecode'=>$req->drpcode,
            'mobilenumber'=>$req->txtnumber,
            'otp'=>$otp
        ]
        ]);
        $response = $response->getBody();
        return json_decode($response,true);
}
```

you can retrieve it by

```
public function otpverify(Request $req)
 {
    $otpenter=$req->txtotp;

    //CHANGES
    session_start();
    $otp = $_SESSION['otp']


    if ($otpenter==$otp) 
    {
        return redirect()->action('JaincountController@create')
    }
    else
    {
        return view('jaincount_user/verification');
    }
}
```

let us use laravel session
(documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session)

```
//important 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;


public function makeRequest(Request $req)
   {
        $client = new Client();
        $otp=rand(10000,4);
        // $data=
        $data = array('adhar'=>$req->txtadharnumber,'drp'=>$req->drpcode,'mobilenumber'=>$req->txtnumber);

        //CHANGES
        Session::put('otp',$otp)


        $response = $client->request('POST','http://192.168.1.9/jaincountapi/public/api/otpsms',[
        'form_params'=>[
            'adharcardnumber'=>$req->txtadharnumber,
            'mobilecode'=>$req->drpcode,
            'mobilenumber'=>$req->txtnumber,
            'otp'=>$otp
        ]
        ]);
        $response = $response->getBody();
        return json_decode($response,true);
}
```

you can retrieve it by

```
//important 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

public function otpverify(Request $req)
 {
    $otpenter=$req->txtotp;

    //CHANGES
    $otp = Session::get('otp') //best way to use is flash. see the full documentation


    if ($otpenter==$otp) 
    {
        return redirect()->action('JaincountController@create')
    }
    else
    {
        return view('jaincount_user/verification');
    }
}
```